# Change Weight per unit, while shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipment

I am facing a serious problem with my courior company, whenever I proceed the shipment of any order, the weight canculated per product is 1 kg and so I get charged from the courier company accodingly and I have to go with a long procedure to explain them.

So if there any way i can set it to 250 grams or so, where my every product will be counted as 250 grams when I create a shipment of any order.

Comment: which shipping method do you use?

Answer (score 0):

To set product weight into 250 grams for shipping you need to use an extension by StorePep.

Using StorePep you can set the product weight to 250 grams, let me show you how.

Within your StorePep dashboard you can add an automation rule: 
[image: Automation rule for weight]
As you can see the above image for choose automation criteria add condition "any", And for Action details add action "set package weight".

If you do not know the exact value then you can add different action "adjust package weigh" and "add" or "subtract" percentage of value.

You can find the extension here for [Magento 1](https://marketplace.magento.com/storepep-storepep-shippingcalculator.html) and [Magento 2](https://marketplace.magento.com/storepep-shippingcalculator.html).
You can read storepep's [documentation on shipping automation rule.](https://www.storepep.com/automation-rules-in-storepep/)

Comment: i will check on this, thanks a lot

Comment: I tired its paid version, actually the courier company told me to find the payroll section and set weight there. So do you know where can i find this file or so.